# Apple's Emoji keyboard from my custom keyboard

Tags: ios, emoji, custom-keyboard

How can I call Apple's Emoji keyboard from my custom keyboard?

[image: Apple's emoji keyboard button example]

Comment: Are you want to use basic emojis or else..

Comment: I just want to have button, which will navigate to Apple's emoji keyboard.

Comment: you can't directly navigate to apple emoji keyboard you just need to follow the few steps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. The only thing you can do (and must do to be approved by Apple), is to call [advanceToNextInputMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIInputViewController/advanceToNextInputMode).

> To ask the system to switch to another keyboard, call the
> advanceToNextInputMode method of the UIInputViewController class. The
> system picks the appropriate “next” keyboard; there is no API to
> obtain a list of enabled keyboards or for picking a particular
> keyboard to switch to.

From the section [Providing a Way to Switch to Another Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html).

However, you could create a button that changes the layout/keys of your Keyboard to Emoji-Style